# Métodos get e set no java para boolean e char

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um código que utiliza os metodos get e set para entrada e processamento dos dados. O objetivo é entrada com 9 valores cada um com um tipo de dado, mas não estou conseguindo fazer as conversões para o tipo char e para o tipo boolean.

```
package javaapplication2;

public class Geladeira {
    char classificacao;
    short garantia;
    String cor;
    int voltagem;
    long totalLitros;
    double preco;
    float consumo;
    byte puxadores;
    boolean iluminacao;

    //Metodo setter
    public void setClassificacao(char c){
        classificacao = c;
    }

    public void setGarantia(short g){
        garantia = g;
    }

    public void setCor (String a){
        cor = a;
    }

    public void setVoltagem(int v){
        voltagem = v;
    }

    public void setTotalLitros(long t){
        totalLitros = t;
    }

    public void setPreco(double p){
        preco = p;
    }

    public void setConsumo(float con){
        consumo = con;
    }

    public void setPuxadores(byte px){
        puxadores = px;
    }

    public void setIlumincao(boolean i){
        iluminacao = i;
    }


    //Metodo getter
    public char getClassificacao(){
        return classificacao;
    }

    public short getGarantia(){
        return garantia;
    }

    public String getCor(){
        return cor;
    }

    public int getVoltagem(){
        return voltagem;
    }

    public long getTotalLitros(){
        return totalLitros;
    }

    public double getPreco(){
        return preco;
    }

    public float getConsumo(){
        return consumo;
    }

    public byte getPuxadores(){
        return puxadores;
    }

    public boolean getIlimunacao(){
        return iluminacao;
    }

    void getGarantia(short parseShort) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

E:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner SC = new Scanner (System.in);

        Geladeira dadosG = new Geladeira();

        System.out.println("Digite a classificação energética: ");
        dadosG.setClassificacao(SC.next());

        System.out.println("Digite a garantia: ");
        dadosG.setGarantia(Short.parseShort(SC.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Digite a cor: ");
        dadosG.setCor(SC.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Digite a voltagem: ");
        dadosG.setVoltagem(Integer.parseInt(SC.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Digite o total de litros: ");
        dadosG.setTotalLitros(Long.parseLong(SC.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Digite o preço: ");
        dadosG.setPreco(Double.parseDouble(SC.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Digite o consumo: ");
        dadosG.setConsumo(Float.parseFloat(SC.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de puxadores: ");
        dadosG.setPuxadores(Byte.parseByte(SC.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Digite 1 se exitir ilimuninação interna ou 0 caso não exista: ");
        dadosG.getIlimunacao(Boolean.parseBollean(SC.nextLine()));


    }

}
```

Comment: `parseBollean` está mal escrito, e espera que seja escrito `true` ou `false` e não `0` ou `1`. Sempre que estiver na duvida [confirme na documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o next com regex:

```
// Aceita um caracter de a até f
dadosG.setClassificacao(SC.next("[a-f]").charAt(0));

// Aceita um caracter de 0 até 1
dadosG.setIlumincao(!SC.next("[0-1]").equals("0"));
```

Lembrando que você precisa tratar a exceção de InputMismatch, caso o que o usuário digite não seja o que você espera.